# Google Transfer Service from AdWords to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

We are using google's transfer service in order to export data from AdWords directly into BigQuery.

While everything seems to work fine, the campaigns' cost is roughly 50% of the actual cost.

I'm referring to table `CampaignStats` and to field 'Cost' (divided by 1 million of course).

Example of a query is:

```
select Date, sum (Cost)/1000000 Cost
from `adwords.CampaignStats_xxxxxxxxxx`
where Date >= '2018-06-01'
group by Date
order by Date
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any thoughts here?

Comment: Is the value of the cost wrong only when you run the query? Or is it wrong in the BigQuery table even without running the query?

Comment: It is wrong in the table even without running the query. very frustrating :)

Comment: Hi, we took a deep look at the costs. It turns our that if we look at table `p_CampaignStats_*` in field 'AdNetworkType1' then all costs are correct, excluding costs that come with AdNetworkType1 = 'CONTENT'. Can someone please advise?